# PCB specs, Meaning of "6-1" diameter

Tags: pcb, relay, dimensions, drill

I'm using a relay for a PCB, but have trouble understanding some of the specs for the recommended hole drill sizes.
As shown below, the spec sheet indicates a "6-1" diameter hole.

What is the meaning of this 6-1?

It should be something with a diameter of less than 2.22 mm, but it would be helpful to know an exact dimension in case the drawing was not to scale.

[image]
https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5v_1.pdf

Comment: Sure looks like 1mm D holes (6) yet is has almost the same radius as 1.11 (?). So it could mean radius ( non-std )

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: It seems the holes are not drawn to scale 0.5mm pins with 1 mm holes makes sense but the centre to case edge is Ok but the circles are drawn too big to scale

Comment: 6 holes, 1 mm diameter. (If it were radius, it wouldn't say "dia") I agree the rings are too large, may reflect the PCB pads.

Comment: 6 times 1mm hole.

Comment: It ought to say Not to scale for the holes , but then I recall an old drafstman in ‘it who made little circles too big so they can be microfiched then  enlarged and not disappear or look like dust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of this 6-1?

It means there are 6 holes, and the dimension of 1 mm diameter applies to all of them.

Comment: The confusion is the scale of 1mmD does not match dimensions 1.11mm or 1.07mm

Comment: @Tony, The 1.11 mm dimension is between the center of the hole and the outline of the part, not the radius of the hole. If you imagine the hole diameter is on the inner edge of the drawn lines, it's not that far out of scale.

Comment: I can measure 25% pixel error, but I understood it was a drafting syntax issue

Answer (score 2):

It's not drawn to scale. It means 6 places of 1mm diameter holes. To scale it looks like this:

[image]

The 1mm\$\phi\$ holes are already pretty sloppy for 0.5mm pins.

They're drawn as 1.52mm +/- 0.15mm by my reckoning, so about 50% too large.

It's not drafted particularly well, the 7.62 dimension should probably be in parenthesis.